# Dynamic %%GLOBAL_UPC%% variable on blueprint theme

Tags: product, bigcommerce, blueprint

I would like to know if the global variable **%%GLOBAL_UPC%%** (UPC/EAN) can be changed dynamically as the SKU variable does too.

The UPC fields appears inside of Options &SKU tab from backend. But only display the first value when i display  %%GLOBAL_UPC%% in product page.

Exist some javascript or method to show the others values when changing options??

Remember that im talking about UPC (Not SKU) using the blueprint theme.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be changed dynamically like the SKU. There is only a single UPC value per parent product in the BigCommerce data model.